# Categorize social events

Tags: machine-learning, nlp

I am having name and description of event and i want to find out about the categories of the event(for example is it entertainment event, politic event or something else).
 I was searching on the web and i looked at some natural language processing  techniques such as Latent Dirichlet Allocation but i can not see a way to use it in my situation. 
Is it a good idea to try to categorize by having predefined keywords for each category, and then to query the text and decide by the amount of keywords from each category?
Can someone give me a clue about my problem ? Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach you could take is to start simple and use a bayesian classifier to analyze/classify your data.

I would approach this problem by taking your dataset and splitting it into a training dataset and a non-training dataset. Then, manually review each event and categorize it as a type of event. Using this training dataset to run your classifier against the remainder of your data.

This may not be ideal for a large amount of event types but it might be a way for you to get started addressing the problem.